# read a single line json in spark where column key is variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a single line json file such as the following

```
{"Hotel Dream":{"Guests":20,"Address":"14 Naik Street","City":"Manila"},"Serenity Stay":{"Guests":35,"Address":"10 St Marie Road","City":"Manila"}....}
```

If I use the following to read the json to spark context, it results in

```
val hotelDF = sqlContext.read.json("file").printSchema

root
 |-- Hotel Dream: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Guests: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Serenity Stay: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Address: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Guests: long (nullable = true)
```

I would like to transpose the varying columns (Hotel Dream, Serenity Stay etc) such that the dataframe ends up in a regularised schema

```
Hotel: string (nullable = true)
Guests: string (nullable = true)
Address: string (nullable = true)
City: string (nullable = true)
```

Also tried injesting the json as a textFile or wholeTextFiles. But since there is no newline demiliter, I can't map the contents with a map function.

Any inputs on how to read such a data format?

Answer (score -1):

Following can be your solution from what I understood from your question ( its not a perfect solution though)

```
var newDataFrame = Seq(("test", "test", "test", "test")).toDF("Hotel", "Address", "City", "Guests")
for(name <- hotelDF.schema.fieldNames) {
  val tempdf = hotelDF.withColumn("Hotel", lit(name))
    .withColumn("Address", hotelDF(name + ".Address"))
    .withColumn("City", hotelDF(name + ".City"))
    .withColumn("Guests", hotelDF(name + ".Guests"))
  val tdf = tempdf.select("Hotel", "Address", "City", "Guests")
  newDataFrame = newDataFrame.union(tdf)
}
newDataFrame.filter(!(col("Hotel") === "test")).show
```